# Powershell Form - Change visibility

Tags: powershell, user-interface, progress-bar

I have a powershell script with a simple form which is working.  It runs an external application (USMT scanstate / loadstate) and the functionality is all fine.

However when it's running the user has no feedback that it is working, so initial users were thinking something had gone wrong.

I've added a marquee progress bar to run at the bottom of the form to indicate it is working.

I can use the:

```
$progressbar1.visible = $False
```

Property to show whether it is visible or not, but I'm not sure how to make this dynamic.  If I set to **false** then call the form with **.ShowDialog()** then try to change it later to **True** nothing actually changes in the form.

Am I missing something?  Is there a way to dynamically change the visibility of a form object?

EDIT :: Adding the **.Visible** property change to the **.add_click** of the button.

```
$buttonYes.add_click({$progressbar1.visible = $True;Action $type;$confirm.Close()})
```

This does get the progress bar to appear, however the Marquee is not running which is strange, so it just shows an blank box...

EDIT 2 :: OK so looks like it does work,  but only when run from the ISE.  I've tried it on another system and running from command line or shortcut doesn't work.  I've tried setting **STA** but still no go,  the progress bar shows but now Marquee effect.

Comment: Is there a Go button or are you using something like the on load event?

Comment: You put me in the right direction,  I'm an idiot and put the .Visible event AFTER the command run,  so the command was running first for a time, then the progress bar was displaying (and the form immediately closing).